# New Styles in C#

Tags: c#, idioms, fluent-interface

Fluent APIs are very common these days. Lately, I'm finding them in almost every system I work with. Mostly, they enhance readability but sometimes they lock me in to inflexible specifications, making understanding the runtime behavior of the specification that they build almost impossible. Is there a consensus on how to create a good fluent API? What are the best ways to represent a structure or specification using a fluent API?

I recently noticed this novel variant on the fluent API in the [NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.com) configuration class:

```
class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server { }
```

It uses multiple interfaces as a kind of linear fluent interface. I like it because it doesn't place a heavy burden of extra code and context on me when I'm only trying to represent simple requirements. In simple cases that is adequate. I don't imagine it would scale to complex specifications, though. What do you think of this use of interfaces?

What other new idioms are you using in C#? Where do you use them? What are their strengths? Where wouldn't you use them? Also, how would you gauge the strengths of an idiom you were thinking of using?

Comment: At the very least make this Community Wiki.

Comment: Why? This is not going to generate answers that will be true for all time - idioms change, hence why I'm asking for an update!

Answer (score 1):

I used to eschew boolean parameters on methods that indicated different behavior, e.g. I would take

`int ExpensiveComputation(bool useDiskCache)`

and prefer to turn it into

`int ExpensiveComputation(CacheType.DiskCache)`

I mostly preferred this because when you're calling `ExpensiveComputation(true)`, it's not clear what the `true` means without knowing all about `ExpensiveComputation`, whereas `ExpensiveComputation(CacheType.DiskCache)` gives you a good idea.

However, with named parameters, I find it often acceptable to use the first, and call it like this: `ExpensiveComputation(useDiskCache: true)`  So that's a recent idiom I've invented for myself.

Comment: Nice. I guess the fluent approach (which I hasten to add is worse than what you're proposing) to this would use your old way of doing things but naming the parameters to provide fluency: ExpensiveCalculation(using: DiskCache); I wonder whether this is in use anywhere?